# error C2678: no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Full error info:

```
error C2678: no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

With the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct num_pair
{
    int num1, num2;
};

struct coord {
    int y;
    int x;
};

struct state_info {
    vector<string> lines;
    coord o;
    bool flag;
};

bool is_solved(state_info m) {
    bool check = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.lines.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.lines[i].size(); j++) {
            check *= (m.lines[i][j] != 'x');
        }
    }
    return check;
}

state_info try_move(state_info m, num_pair direction) {
//implementation
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    string filename = argv[1];
    ifstream file;
    file.open(filename, ios::in);


    vector<string> lines;

    int line_num = 0;
    coord o;
    while (!file.eof()) {
        line_num++;
        string str;
        getline(file, str);
        str = str.substr(0, str.length() - 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str[i] == 'o' || 'O') {
                o.y = line_num;
                o.x = i;
            }
        }
        lines.push_back(str);
    }
    file.close();

    map <char, num_pair> DYDX;

    map <state_info, vector<char>> visited;
    state_info temp;
    temp.lines = lines;
    temp.o = o;
    temp.flag = true;
    vector<char> temp1;
    visited[temp] = temp1;
    queue <state_info> state;//todo
    state.push(temp);
    while (state.size() != 0) {
        state_info currstate = state.front();
        if (is_solved(currstate)) {
            vector<char> output = visited[currstate];
            for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++) cout << output[i];
        }
        map<char, num_pair>::iterator iter;
        map<state_info, vector<char>>::iterator it;
        for (iter = DYDX.begin(); iter != DYDX.end(); iter++) {
            num_pair move = (*iter).second;
            state_info newstate = try_move(currstate, move);
            if (newstate.flag) {
                it = visited.find(newstate);
                if (it == visited.end()) {
                    temp1 = visited[currstate];
                    temp1.push_back((*iter).first);
                    visited[newstate] = temp1;
                    state.push(newstate);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It comes out with a compilation error C2678 which seems to be that somewhere in the code exists a operation that assign a non-const variable to a const. I have no idea where to begin with the debugging.

I checked where this error comes from and it lead me to this section of code.

```
template<class _Ty = void>
    struct less
    {   // functor for operator<
    _CXX17_DEPRECATE_ADAPTOR_TYPEDEFS typedef _Ty first_argument_type;
    _CXX17_DEPRECATE_ADAPTOR_TYPEDEFS typedef _Ty second_argument_type;
    _CXX17_DEPRECATE_ADAPTOR_TYPEDEFS typedef bool result_type;

    constexpr bool operator()(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right) const
        {   // apply operator< to operands
        return (_Left < _Right);
        }
    };
```

Why does this error happen? Is it because of the STL that I use? And any suggestions how to find out where the problem is with the output council?

Comment: Way too much code, delete parts of it until it doesn't reproduce the problem, then put the minimum back and delete more parts.

Comment: `while (!file.eof())` is  a logic error (not related to the error message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps are sorted data structures and so need an `operator<` defined on their key type.

```
map <state_info, vector<char>> visited;
```

There is no `operator<` defined for `state_info`. That is what the error message is telling you.

There are other ways to solve this problem. If defining `operator<` for `state_info` seems unnatural to you, then you could pass a comparator type to your map declaration.

```
map <state_info, vector<char>, state_info_cmp> visited;
```

with

```
struct state_info_cmp
{
    bool operator()(const state_info& x, const state_info& y) const
    {
        // true if x is 'less than' y, false otherwise
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So either I overload my state_info structure with operator< or I add what you mention above will be good enough. Is it correct?

Comment: If you choose operator< you should define it as a global function, in general that works better than making it a member of state_info, or you can pick the other method. Either way you are writing a function that compares two state_info objects and return true if one is less than the other, whatever you choose 'less than' to mean. Also be aware that your comparison function must define a strict weak ordering.

Comment: @EricYu Added const to the signature of the comparator. That's necessary.